# Joining Multiple Tables Order

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to join a few different tables to one table. I am not getting the exact output that I am looking for and I am wondering if I am joining them in a wrong order.

Basically I just want to Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old.  But I there are also tables that won't join directly to the main table.  So I have to join the together before being able to join them to Q2IMSSiteHistory2015Old.

```
Select Hsp.HspId, CMSid as MSFacility
From Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old
Right Join HSP on Cast(HSP.CMSid as nvarchar) = Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old.POS
right Join Q2IMSSurgeonHistory2015 on Q2IMSSurgeonHistory2015.POS = Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old.POS
Right join SurgeonMaster on SurgeonMaster.NPI = Q2IMSSurgeonHistory2015.NPI
Group by Hsp.HspId, CMSId
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What output do you want? We can't guess.

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.

Comment: Any specific reason to use right join . Will there be non-matching records that you need to care for. You mention that you want Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old but your select columns are from HSP table.

Comment: Right Joins include all records from the table on the right and records which match on the left side So All records from surgeon master returned and only those matching Q2IMSSurgeonHistory2015 and repeat for each join.  So what is it that you want ??  all records from Q2IMSSiteHistory2015Old  and releated from others?  if so perhaps a left join instead of right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't set a length on your nvarchar it will be truncated to 1 character.

```
DECLARE @txt AS NVARCHAR

SET @txt = 'hello'
SELECT @txt
```

--Result = 'h'

TRY:

```
Select Hsp.HspId, CMSid as MSFacility
From Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old
Right Join HSP on Cast(HSP.CMSid as nvarchar(255)) = Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old.POS
right Join Q2IMSSurgeonHistory2015 on Q2IMSSurgeonHistory2015.POS = Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old.POS
Right join SurgeonMaster on SurgeonMaster.NPI = Q2IMSSurgeonHistory2015.NPI
Group by Hsp.HspId, CMSId
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that "rule" depends on the context. Casting to char/nchar will use an implied length of 30 if none is provided. But is it good to always specify the length regardless.